# Que significa el siguiente error: Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

Tags: matriz

Estoy buscando rellenar una matriz a partir de una lista. Para ello, primero creo la matriz vacia y luego la intento rellenar con un loop de la siguiente forma:

```
VAX_large <- matrix(0, n * p * n * p, 5)

for(i in 1:p) {
  e <- i * n
  s <- e - n + 1
  VAX.temp <- VAX_list[[i]]
  df_vaxtemp <- melt(VAX.temp)
  colnames(df_vaxtemp) <- c("columna1", "columna2", "ingreso")
  str_split_fixed(df_vaxtemp$columna1, "_", 2)
  str_split_fixed(df_vaxtemp$columna2, "_", 2)
  VAX_large[(s:e), ] <- df_vaxtemp
  rm(VAX.temp, df_vaxtemp, s, e, i)
}
```

Cuando corro el loop me aparece el siguiente error:

```
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
```

Alguien me puede decir qué significa y cómo solucionarlo?
Gracias

Comment: ¿Y esto que lenguaje es? ¿R? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y coloca la etiqueta correspondiente. Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.